# How to set​Request​Header on AMP-FORM?

Tags: amp-html, amp-form

How can I add an 'x-access-token' header to an AMP-FORM xhr request?

There's a java API that I'm going to send some requests to, but this API needs that some params be set via request headers.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently not possible. However, you could file a [feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%3A%20Feature%20Request&template=feature_request.md&title=) as this might be a common use case.